# Why do I get a SerializationException if I do not copy my .NET dll into the Office application folder?

Tags: .net, excel, remoting

I am referencing a C# dll from Excel VBA. This C# dll connects to a .NET Remote Service. One of the types that the Remote Service passes as a parameter, TSConditionList, is contained in general.dll. If I do not copy general.dll to the Office application folder then I get a serialization exception, because the SoapFormatter doesn't have the correct type information.

---

My C# dll is TarsanExcelConnector.dll. I use REGASM to register this C# dll at the fixed location 'C:\TarsanExcelConnector'.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Regasm.exe TarsanExcelConnector.dll /codebase /tlb:TarsanExcelConnector.tlb

In the 'C:\TarsanExcelConnector' directory I have a number of DLL's that are referenced by TarsanExcelConnector.dll:

- general.dll
- TradeSourceParsers.dll
- TradeSourcePureDataAdapter.dll

All three of these assemblies are correctly located and loaded into the AppDomain.

My VBA code is as follows:

```
Public Function GetTradesDebug(url As String, conditionList() As Variant, contextMap() As Variant) As String
Dim TTSConnection As New TarsanExcelConnector.TarsanExcelConnector
GetTradesDebug = TTSConnection.GetTradesDebug(url, conditionList, contextMap)
End Function
```

This fails with the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Invalid method signature 'a1:TSConditionList a2:StringDictionary'.  Server stack trace:     at     System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapHandler.ProcessType(ParseRecord pr, ParseRecord objectPr)    at     System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapHandler.ProcessAttributes(ParseRecord pr, ParseRecord objectPr)       at     System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapHandler.EndElement(String prefix, String name, String urn)       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapParser.ParseXml()       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapParser.Run()       at     System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.ObjectReader.Deserialize       (HeaderHandler handler, ISerParser serParser)       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler)       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.DeserializeSoapResponseMessage(Stream inputStream, IMessage requestMsg, Header[] h, Boolean bStrictBinding)       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SoapClientFormatterSink.DeserializeMessage(IMethodCallMessage mcm, ITransportHeaders headers, Stream stream)       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SoapClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)     Exception rethrown at [0]:        at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)       at GFX.Services.ITradeSourceService.GetTrades(TSConditionList conditionList, StringDictionary contextMap)       at GFX.Services.Pure.TradeSourceClient.GetTrades(TSConditionList conditionList, StringDictionary contextMap)       at TTSConnector.TarsanTradeSourceConnector.GetTrades(String tssUrl, Object[,] tssConditionList, Object[,] tssContextMap) in        C:\new_code\TTSConnector\TTSConnector\TarsanTradeSourceConnector.cs:line 99       at TTSConnector.TarsanTradeSourceConnector.GetTradesDebug(String tssUrl, Object[,] tssConditionList, Object[,] tssContextMap) in C:\new_code\TTSConnector\TTSConnector\TarsanTradeSourceConnector.cs:line 66
```

---

If I copy general.dll into the office application directory then I do not get this exception.

For Windows 7/Excel 2010 I copy to here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\general.dll

For Windows XP/Excel 2003 I copy to here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\general.dll

I don't understand why the SoapFormatter is not seeing the general.dll in the 'C:\TarsanExcelConnector' directory?? If I check the assemblies that are loaded into the AppDomain I can see that it is definately loading the assembly from 'C:/TarsanExcelConnector/general.DLL'.

---

When I wrote some test methods to find the troublesome type, the much more useful SerializationException I got was something like this: 'Parse Error, no assembly associated with Xml key TSConditionList'. This type is contained in general.dll.

If the runtime loads the assembly from C:\TarsanExcelConnector then it can't find the type. If the runtime loads the assembly from the Office directory, then the Serialization succeeds. WHY?

Answer (score 0):

I think REGASM doesn't help in this case. The problem is, that the .net runtime doesn't seem to find your DLL.

You should try the fusion log viewer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.71).aspx

This tool lets you see what DLLs are loaded from your application and if there are any failures.

Also, whenever the runtime tries to locate a DLL it fires the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event which you can handle to resolve the path to your DLL.

Hope it helps!